# JQuery Tablesorter - leave the first row intact

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, customization, tablesorter

I am using the [jQuery Tablesorter 2.0 plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to create a sortable table of ... say books.
The very first row of the table will be a summary of all books, and I want it to always be at the top.

I need to customize the behavior of the tablesorter, but I do not think I can/should do that with a custom parser. What I think I need is a custom comparator function - one that would allow me to compare any two rows myself, ideally also being able to invoke the default behavior if the condition that I am looking for has not been met.

Sample algorithm would be like so (hopefully I did not invert my result):

```
function customSort(lhs, rhs, table, column_index) {
    if (lhs === 'magic_str') {
        return -1; // Magic string wins
    }
    if (rhs === 'magic_str') {
        return 1; // Magic string wins
    }
    return defaultSort(lhs, rhs, table, column_index);
}
```

Now, I know some JS but not enough to pry a popular library open and rewrite parts of it, particularly as a patch that would go on top, after I load the original. (that would be ideal). Also, if I can accomplish this sort of behavior in any other way, I am all ears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easier solution would be to try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) and just put that row you don't want to sort into a separate tbody - this won't work with the original tablesorter.

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tablesorter-infoOnly">
        ... <!-- non-sorting tbody -->
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Since it is only one row, you don't really need to add the "tablesorter-infoOnly" class name; it does prevent column styling being applied to it. Try out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1379/) and remove the tbody class name to see the difference.

And FYI, you can add any number of tbodies to the table.

Comment: Thank you, looks very promising. I am doing some extra things like having two rows of headers, one for meta purposes with multiple column span and not to be sorted on. One column is hidden. Also, I add and remove rows quite a bit, and the original tablesorter would sometimes mess things up then. Hopefully you would not mind if I contacted you should I get stuck.

Comment: Two rows in the header, info tbody, footer, etc shouldn't be a problem. Hidden columns may not be necessary; but that all depends on what you want to do with that data. Please feel free to ask for any help if you need it :)

Comment: Ok, here is a question. I have two rows in thead and I only want to sort on the second tr of thead. So, I use this setting:   `headers: { 0: { sorter: "digit" }, 1: { sorter: "text" }, 2: { sorter: "text" }, ...}`. I believe that this gets applied to the top header row. It is as if I need a `headers2` key as wel, or I should specify 2D coordinates of my header cell. Hopefully the question makes sense. I can currently use `headers` key to turn off sorting in the first of two headers but I cannot use the same property to specify data type for the second row in the header. `sortList` applies to?

Comment: You can just add a `sorter-false` class name to the cell you want to ignore. The header option numbering (0, 1, 2, 3, etc) also applies to the header cell index. `SortList` applies to the column, not the header index. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1395/

Comment: Ah, I did not think that every header cell is identifiable by a single index. That makes perfect sense now that I think about it. Thank you sir! Your fork of the tablesorter works very well and is very easy to use. It should be more popular.

Comment: Hi @Mottie, quick question - Right now the text for every other row is bold. How can I change that so that neither odd nor even rows are bold?

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the css.

Comment: Ineed it was, Chrome's "Inspect Element" on a bold row pointed me to the suspect - jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css that had `font-weight: bold;` for `.ui-state-default`. Thanks again.